# Single window auto-maximimizing

Tags: window-manager, awesome-wm

There are some superfluous padding in Awesome windows manager in case of unmaximized single window. I'm talking about window borders and other specific for certain applications stuff (for example Chromium has more compact upper panel in maximized mode).

**Is it possible to make Awesome auto-maximize window when windows count equals one?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Check [client signals](https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Signals#client)!

The code of my main idea (maybe not perfect):

```
client.connect_signal("tagged",function(c,new_tag)
   if ( #(new_tag:clients())==1 ) then
       c.maximized_horizontal = true
       c.maximized_vertical = true
   end
end)

client.connect_signal("untagged",function(c,old_tag)
   if ( #(old_tag:clients())==1 ) then
       local myclients = old_tag:clients()
       for _,cl in ipairs(myclients) do             
          cl.maximized_horizontal = true
          cl.maximized_vertical = true
       end
   end
end)
```